# Is the Dirichlet eta a bounded function?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We say that a function $f:A→A$ is bounded if: There exist a positive real number $M $ such that $$|f(z)|≤M$$ for all $z$ in the set $A$.

My **question** is: Is the Dirichlet eta function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) is bounded in the sense of the above defition. Here $A$ is the set in the complex plane with $Re(z)>0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is written in the wikipedia page you linked, the Dirichlet eta function can be extended to an entire function, i.e. a function that is holomorphic on the whole complex plane. But by [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)), such a  function, if it is bounded, is necessarily constant, which is clearly not the case.

Edit: as pointed out in the comments this answer is not appropriate because I considered the boundedness of the extension $\tilde{\eta}$ of the Dirichlet eta function (with domain $\mathbb{C}$) rather than the Dirichlet  eta function $\eta$ defined on $\Re (z)>0$.

However, suppose by contradiction that $\eta$ is bounded, i.e. $\tilde{\eta}$ is bounded for $\Re(s)>0$, with $|\tilde{\eta}(s)|=|\eta(s)|\leq M$. The relation  (which you can also find in the wikipedia page)
$$\tilde{\eta}(-s)=2\frac{1-2^{-s-1}}{1-2^{-s}}\pi^{-s-1}s\cdot \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2} \right)\Gamma(s)\eta(s+1)$$
holds for all $s$ with $\Re(s)\geq 0$ (notice that in this case, $\Re(-s)\leq 0$, and $\Re(s+1)>0$). Moreover, the term in the right-hand-side is bounded for $\Re(s)\geq 0$ and therefore for some $M'>0$ we have
$$|\tilde{\eta}(-s)|\leq M',\qquad \forall s:\Re(s)\geq 0$$
and hence 
$$ |\tilde{\eta}(s)|\leq \max\left\{M;M'\right\},\qquad \forall s\in \mathbb{C}$$
i.e. the entire function $\tilde{\eta}$ is bounded and non-constant, contradicting Liouville's theorem.

EDIT: The answer is still wrong. Even if $\eta(s+1)$ is bounded, the term in the right hand side is unbounded for $\Re(s)>0$ due to $\Gamma(s)$ growing faster than an exponential as $\Re(s)\to +\infty$.

I will delete this answer as soon as @reuns posts his own - which for now is sketched in the comments below this answer.

Comment: Yes but on $\Re(z) > 0$, $\eta(z+2)$ is bounded but non constant. To see $\eta(z)$ is unbounded on $\Re(z) = 1$ you can use $\log(\eta(z)) = \sum_p p^{-s}+O(1)$, that the arguments $\log p$ are $\mathbb{Z}$-linearly independent and  $\sum_p p^{-1} = \infty$

Comment: @reuns  yes you are correct, I will try to update my answer or otherwise delete it.

Comment: I meant $\log(\eta(z)) = \log(1-2^{1-z}) + \sum_p p^{-z} + O(1)$ and for a fixed $\sigma > 1$, choosing well $t$ you can approximate $\sum_p p^{-\sigma}$ by $\log(\eta(\sigma+it))$

Comment: The $\Gamma(s)$ in the functional equation grows very fast as $\Re(s) \to \infty$. Your argument would work the same way with $\eta(s+2)$ which is bounded on $\Re(s) > 0$ but not on $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Agreed. I will delete my answer then, I suggest that you post your proof (as an answer) with all the details.